# How to design Facebook invitation buttons

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, angular

I want to show my Facebook invitation. I have two buttons: one for sending dialog and another for requesting dialog. I'm using Angular framework. The buttons I have, do not have a style on the component footer. I need to style them like on other styles. I am using Facebook SDK for Javascript. But I can't use its style classes, so I need to design my own style, or grab the style somewhere on the Facebook site. The login button doesn't work for me. Either I need to show the login button style or replace its look and feel with custom button handler. The code I have now doesn't look like Facebook invitation buttons. I need a help to design this buttons to have corresponding look and feel. The help is appreciated.

```
           <div class="form-group" *ngIf="socialPanelEnabled" ui-view xfbml-parse>
            <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
   <!--
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" (click)="send()">Send</button>
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" (click)="apprequests()">Request</button>
               -->
            </div>
```

Comment: You can not style the Facebook buttons apart from the options the configurator tools offer. If you want your own styles, then you should not be using the Facebook buttons at all, but create your own, and then call the appropriate functionality onclick yourself.

Comment: I've tried facebook login button, but it doesn't work. I have tried my own buttons but it doesn't have a style that looks like facebook button. Even I don't need a login button functionality but the same style or may be better design.

Comment: You either use the buttons they provide - then you are limited to the _functionality_ they provide as well. Or you create and style your own buttons - up to you.

Comment: Can you give me an example, the code I've tried doesn't work with angular, if I uncomment  the buttons it works fine, but it looks not facebook like. Also I don't wont to confuse share buttons with send.

Comment: You can not put your own HTML elements into those buttons Facebook provides; they get _replaced_ with the content loaded from Facebook.

Comment: Why, sorry am new to facebook, but the content either not loaded or doesn't function. Because it's not *visible*, however I can use send and request iframes even with login dialog if I didn't log in previously. If I see the DOM the div is available.

Comment: The login button is to make user login to _your_ app. Send and Request dialogs don’t need the user to be logged in to your app.

Comment: This is not true, because if I sign out, the login dialog comes first before I can make any request.

Comment: Of course the user has to login to Facebook, before they can use the dialogs. But that is triggered automatically by the Send and Request dialogs, and has nothing to do with your login button.

Comment: I don't mind what is this login button, I guessed from the docs that it opens the same login dialog that allows the user to sign in to Facebook. This is not the problem if it's already integrated with send or request functionality. But there's no buttons for them available and if I try any button like login it doesn't work. I'me close to write some css rules for this issue

Comment: Send Button is available as a social plugin directly from Facebook. If you want a similar style for other buttons not generated by Facebook - then you will have to style them yourself.